# Casting float2 to double2 and vice versa

Tags: casting, opencl

So I have an openCL program where some of the variables are in float2 and some are in double2.  And I would like to either upcast or downcast these variables but I am not sure how to do it.  I tried to explicitly casting it like how I would normally do for float and double but it didn't work.

```
float2 a,b;
double2 c,d;

a = (float2)(c+d); //didnt work
a = float2(c+d);  //didnt work
```

Maybe I am not understanding the type "float2" and "double2", could someone tell me how to cast them in order to work properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The floatn and doublen type families represent vectors of values (in your case they have 2 members). A C-style conversion does not work on them.

There is a family of conversion functions that work for vectors that look like this:

```
convert_float2(vec2)
```

However, reading the documentation [here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/) it looks like conversion from/to double2 is not supported. That leaves you with the option of performing the conversions manually:

```
a.x = float(c.x + d.x);
a.y = float(c.y + d.y);
```